# Does NSFetchedResultController ignores changes in some cases?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my current app I am currently using MagicalRecord for importing data from a REST API with a UITableView implementing a NSFetchedResultController.

The case where the problem occurs:

1. I setup a NSFetchedResultController with the predicate as following: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"friend_type != %i", FacebookFriend];
2. First I retrieve friends from Facebook which get the friend_type FacebookFriend (from enum).
3. I will try to resolve their Facebook ID's with a REST API call.
4. If users were resolved I will change their friend_type to ResolvedFacebookFriend (from enum)
5. The NSFetchedResultController wont be notified with these changes.

See the following code for initializing my NSFetchedResultController and importing from the data sources.

Creating a NSFetchedResultController via the MagicalRecord library

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"friend_type != %i", FacebookFriend];
self.friendsResultController = [Friend fetchAllGroupedBy:@"friend_type" withPredicate:predicate sortedBy:@"friend_type,user.nickname" ascending:YES delegate:self];
```

Creating the Friend entity via the MagicalRecord library after the first API call was made to Facebook:

```
Friend* userFriend = [Friend createEntity];
userFriend.friend_type = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:FacebookFriend];
```

Updating these FacebookFriends if they were resolved by my local REST API:

```
Friend* userFriend = [Friend ....] // Correct friend was fetched
userFriend.friend_type = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:ResolvedFacebookFriend];
```

What could i do to make the NSFetchedResultController be notified by these changes? If not is this a bug of Apple or should I setup my CoreData in a different way?

**Edit - 14 November 2013**

I found out when the object is saved with the friend_type ResolvedFacebookFriend. And saving it again like this:

```
userFriend.friend_type = userFriend.friend_type;
// Save the context again
```

The NSFetchedResultController sees the change all of a sudden and inserts a row into the UITableView.

Comment: The FRC has a delegate?

Comment: Yes with the normal methods implemented like everywhere. controllerWillChangeContent etc

Comment: Are the updates from the REST API done in another managed object context? If yes, is that context merged succesfully with the 'main' context?

Comment: Yes and yes they are succesfully merged. i found something out and I will update my post.

Comment: What about the FetchedResultController cache? try to reset

Comment: [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil]; did not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370521/changing-a-managedobject-property-doesnt-trigger-nsfetchedresultscontroller-to seems to be sort of the same?

Comment: @Wesso: Did you have a look at the "possible duplicate"? It seems very similar to your problem and provides a workaround to solve it. - The question that you linked to is about changes of an attribute of a *related* entity. That is also a problem with FRC, but seems to be different from your problem.

Comment: I checked it out, only using: the willAccessValueForKey:nil seems to work out. Still I would think this is kind of the same as what I do in my edit. There should be a better solution.