# NSFetchedResultsController does not update in a particular scenario

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**Core Data has following 2 entities**

- Item
- Order- which has an attribue called `isAdded` of type Boolean.

Item has a one-to-one relationship called `order` with `Order`. `Order` has a one-to-many relationship called `items` with `Item`.

All items have an order. An order can have zero or more items.

I am trying to show all items in a `UITableView` whose `order.isAdded` is `false`.

I am creating `NSFetchedResultsController` as follows-

```swift
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "order.isAdded == NO")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.item?.name, ascending: true)]
return NSFetchedResultsController(
    fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
    managedObjectContext: container.viewContext,
    sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
    cacheName: nil
)
```

In a `UITableViewController`, the `NSFetchedResultsController` is initialized and its delegate is set to observe the changes.

If a new item is created whose `order.isAdded` is false, then the delegate method is called with newIndexPath.

If an item is deleted, then the delegate method is called to inform that the indexPath was removed.

In a particular scenario, the delegate method is not called.

Consider an item whose `order.isAdded` is false. This item is shown in the `UITableView`. If the `order.isAdded` is set to `true`, I expect that the item must be removed from the UITableView. However, no delegate method is called.

**Can anyone point out why this is happening and how to fix this issue?**

Edit- 
This is a duplicate of [Changing a managed object property doesn't trigger NSFetchedResultsController to update the table view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12370521)

Comment: after setting order.isAdded to true are you saving it on maincontext??

Comment: No. I did not save the context. But even after saving, the issue is still observed

Comment: can you show the code for adding observer and when new order is added (isAdded is false) .

Comment: can you update code how you are updating isAdded to true?? are you using the following to check updates??

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)

Comment: I think the answers to the question you linked address both of your points - why it's happening and how to fix it.